# Error: The getter 'context' isn't defined for the class 'OtpPage'

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface, mobile-development

I am trying to get the UI of an OTP screen using flutter, but I am having errors on the FocusScope.of(context) lines. I thought the 'BuildContext context' defined for the class 'OtpPage' should have made this not an issue.

Here is the code;

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import '/routes/route.dart' as route;

class OtpPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const OtpPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(15.0),
        child: AppBar(
          elevation: 0,
          flexibleSpace: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(image: AssetImage('assets/pattern.png'), fit: BoxFit.fill),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(47, 26, 47, 75),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Image.asset(
                    'assets/logo4.png',
                    height: 50,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 26),
              Row(
                children: [
                  Text(
                    'Enter OTP',
                    style: GoogleFonts.inter(
                      textStyle: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                        fontSize: 24,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 28),
              Form(
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        _textFieldOTP(first: true, last: false),
                        _textFieldOTP(first: false, last: false),
                        _textFieldOTP(first: false, last: false),
                        _textFieldOTP(first: false, last: false),
                        _textFieldOTP(first: false, last: true),
                      ],
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 34),
                    Container(
                      height: 45,
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                      child: ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () => Navigator.pushNamed(context, route.resetPassword),
                        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(primary: Color(0xFFFF2957), elevation: 0.0, shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(8.0))),
                        child: Text(
                          'Verify',
                          style: GoogleFonts.inter(
                            textStyle: TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                              fontSize: 15,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _textFieldOTP({required bool first, last}) {
    return Container(
      height: 60,
      width: 52,
      child: AspectRatio(
        aspectRatio: 1.0,
        child: TextField(
          autofocus: true,
          onChanged: (value) {
            if(value.length == 1 && last == false){
              FocusScope.of(context).nextFocus();
            }
            if(value.length == 1 && first == false){
              FocusScope.of(context).previousFocus();
            }
          },
          showCursor: false,
          readOnly: false,
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
          maxLength: 1,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            counter: Offstage(),
            enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderSide: BorderSide(width: 2, color: Colors.black),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
            ),
            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderSide: BorderSide(width: 2, color: Colors.purple),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I keep getting this error at the console;
lib/views/otp.dart:103:29: Error: The getter 'context' isn't defined for the class 'OtpPage'.

- 'OtpPage' is from 'package:untitled/views/otp.dart' ('lib/views/otp.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'context'.
  FocusScope.of(context).nextFocus();

Same error too for the line FocusScope.of(context).previousFocus();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the context object as an argument to you _textFieldOTP method. If not, the context object to refer to in the function will not be found. See below:

```
Widget _textFieldOTP(BuildContext context, {required bool first, last}) {
return Container(
  height: 60,
  width: 52,
  child: AspectRatio(
    aspectRatio: 1.0,
    child: TextField(
      autofocus: true,
      onChanged: (value) {
        if(value.length == 1 && last == false){
          FocusScope.of(context).nextFocus();
        }
        if(value.length == 1 && first == false){
          FocusScope.of(context).previousFocus();
        }
      },
      showCursor: false,
      readOnly: false,
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
      maxLength: 1,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        counter: Offstage(),
        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: BorderSide(width: 2, color: Colors.black),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
        ),
        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: BorderSide(width: 2, color: Colors.purple),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
}
}
```

Then you pass the context object from the build method when calling the function `_textFieldOTP` as shown below:

```
Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    _textFieldOTP(context, first: true, last: false),
                    _textFieldOTP(context, first: false, last: false),
                    _textFieldOTP(context, first: false, last: false),
                    _textFieldOTP(context, first: false, last: false),
                    _textFieldOTP(context, first: false, last: true),
                  ],
                )
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to pass the context to the widget.Try below code,

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import '/routes/route.dart' as route;

class OtpPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const OtpPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(15.0),
        child: AppBar(
          elevation: 0,
          flexibleSpace: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(image: AssetImage('assets/pattern.png'), fit: BoxFit.fill),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(47, 26, 47, 75),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Image.asset(
                    'assets/logo4.png',
                    height: 50,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 26),
              Row(
                children: [
                  Text(
                    'Enter OTP',
                    style: GoogleFonts.inter(
                      textStyle: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                        fontSize: 24,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 28),
              Form(
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        _textFieldOTP(context:context,first: true, last: false),
                        _textFieldOTP(context:context,first: false, last: false),
                        _textFieldOTP(context:context,first: false, last: false),
                        _textFieldOTP(context:context,first: false, last: false),
                        _textFieldOTP(context:context,first: false, last: true),
                      ],
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 34),
                    Container(
                      height: 45,
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                      child: ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () => Navigator.pushNamed(context, route.resetPassword),
                        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(primary: Color(0xFFFF2957), elevation: 0.0, shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(8.0))),
                        child: Text(
                          'Verify',
                          style: GoogleFonts.inter(
                            textStyle: TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                              fontSize: 15,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _textFieldOTP({required BuildContext context,required bool first, last}) {
    return Container(
      height: 60,
      width: 52,
      child: AspectRatio(
        aspectRatio: 1.0,
        child: TextField(
          autofocus: true,
          onChanged: (value) {
            if(value.length == 1 && last == false){
              FocusScope.of(context).nextFocus();
            }
            if(value.length == 1 && first == false){
              FocusScope.of(context).previousFocus();
            }
          },
          showCursor: false,
          readOnly: false,
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
          maxLength: 1,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            counter: Offstage(),
            enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderSide: BorderSide(width: 2, color: Colors.black),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
            ),
            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderSide: BorderSide(width: 2, color: Colors.purple),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```